# How to set default due time in Trello

Tags: trello

In Trello, I mark my daily tasks with a due date, but I want the due time to be midnight as opposed to noon. Currently every time I insert a task I have to change the time to 11:59 PM by hand, I was wondering if there was a way to set the due time automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now when you set new due dates, Trello uses the last time value you set. So it you change a card to be due at 5:00pm, the time will default to 5:00pm the next time you click the due date button.

There's a card for it here: https://trello.com/c/HMZ1Jp6C

Comment: This answer seems right to me, but the link doesn't work. I'm getting "Card not found. / This card may be on a private board. If someone gave you this link, they may need to invite you to one of their boards or teams."